# Jquery and php not pass data between two pages

Tags: php, jquery, radio-button

I have two pages in php and I need that the value of radioButton selection pass to another page, but it not work.
The jquery code of the page that send the data is:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#continue").click(function(){
var val = $("input[@name='opt']:checked").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
        url:'editor.php',
            data:'radio=' + val,
            dataTyoe:'html',
            succes: alert(val)
        });
    }); 
});
```

The html code into the php page is:

```
    <input type="radio" id="opt" name="opt" value="opt1" checked="checked">Opt 1<br/>
    <input type="radio" id="opt" name="opt" value="opt2"/>opt2<br />
    <input type="radio" id="opt" name="opt" value="opt3"/>opt3<br />

    <a href="editor.php" id="continue">Guardar continuar</a><br/>
```

And the code of the page that recive data is the follow.

```
<?php
$valor = $_REQUEST['radio'];
echo $valor
```

?>

Thanks

Comment: after var val = $("input[@name='opt']:checked").val(); insert an alert(val); is it set?

Comment: yes it's set with correct value

Comment: I surrond the code with the tag form and works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some spelling mistakes and need some correction. Try the following code;

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#continue").click(function(){
var val1 = $("input[name='opt']:checked").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:'editor.php',
        data:'radio=' + val1,
        success: function(){
            alert(val1);
        }
    });
}); 

});
```

Comment: Thanks but It does not work, php continued to give me the same error: Undefined index: radio

Comment: Try this 

`var val1 = $("input[name='opt']:checked").val();`

Also make sure your radio buttons are inside `form` tag. I couldn't make it work without having `form` tag.

Answer (score 0):

you misspelled  succes: it should be  success:

Answer (score 0):

You may have some errors : try replacing `dataTyoe:'html'` for `dataType:'html'`, Also `$("input[@name='opt']:checked")` by `$("input[@name=opt]:checked")`... and the success callback too...

It would look like :

```
var val = $("input[@name=opt]:checked").val();
 $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "editor.php",
      data:'radio='+val,
      dataType: "html",
      async:false,
      success: function(){
         alert(val);
      }
   }
);
```

Also you could remove the link from the html :

```
  <a href="#" id="continue">Guardar continuar</a><br/>
```